# hello world for struts

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, struts

i need a hello world code for struts... step by step. latest netbeans 6.9 and struts 2.2. I've tried various hello world program but whenever i go on to implement i get into errors and tomcat 6.0 deployment fails.

Comment: i will also admire a link in any blog but should work.

Comment: what errors? Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: i use netbeans. both on tomcat and glassfish its first deployed and then get undeployed. reason unable to start that. if i copy paste war in webapps it is not extracted when tomcat is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Hello World is [here](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-hello-world-example-1.html). This is a series of simple sample Struts2 programs that are useful. You can get a nice Struts2 plug-in for Netbeans 6.9.1 [here](http://here).

Answer (score 0):

Not Hello World, but just simple [login](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-struts.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, [Struts 2 and netbeans 6](http://beans.seartipy.com/2008/07/30/hello-world-web-application-using-struts-2-in-netbeans-ide-61/)